# Using monkeyrunner: How can I call intents during the execution of an application?

Tags: android, testing, android-intent, monkeyrunner

I have an android application for which I would like to test intent functionality alone. Is it possible with monkeyrunner to

1. start an application
2. create an intent (based on some already established list, and may have extras)
3. startActivity() or startService() with that intent
4. monitor the result of the call

automatically? And how would I go about doing this? I have seen that monkeyrunner uses python/jython, and I'm rather unfamiliar with those.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not familiar with python (and you don't want to experiment with it) you don't have to use monkeyrunner and you can access the same basic functionality, which is provided by an external library called chimpchat, from Java.

The gory details can be found at http://dtmilano.blogspot.ca/2011/11/android-using-monkey-from-java.html.

Using Java what you describe as your requirements will be fairly easy to achieve if you have done it for an Android application already.